# Need help to understand difference between two usages of unordered_map

Tags: logic, unordered-map

I was solving a question where i wrote two pieces of code as follows.
Note: 'mp' is an already filled unordered_map<int,int>.

1.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
 ans+=mp[A[i]+B[j]]; // did this because, if A[i]+B[j] doesn't exist, mp[A[i]+B[j]]=0.
}
```

2. 

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    auto it=mp.find(A[i]+B[j]);
    if(it!=mp.end())
        ans+=it->second;
    }
```

Now sol2 gave me a speedup of around 140 ms than sol1 and this is not due to different runtimes at submissions at different times. This increment stays constant and I can't understand, why it happened? Both codes do the same operation of adding mapped value of A[i]+B[j] (if it exists) to 'ans'.

Comment: Note that there appears to be a formatting bug - please see [this post on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403800/code-block-formatting-looks-ok-in-preview-wrong-in-main-display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece of code isn't just

> adding mapped value of A[i]+B[j] (if it exists) to 'ans'

but also inserting that key into the map with value 0. Not only does that take time by itself, but the map will be larger for next lookups and they can take more time because of that, especially if hashes of `A[i]+B[j]` can be the same.

Comment: Thanku i get it now.